Jolt Conversion remove the empty string from the jolt
Below is the input ,spec and output spec and the expected spce.
here in the outputspec we are getting the tag with the empty values, That empty tag needs to be removed from the output jolt.
Below will be the input spec:
Input spec:
{
  "feature": [],
  "note": [],
  "place": [],
  "relatedEntity": [],
  "relatedParty": [],
  "characteristic": [
    {
      "name": "SerialNo",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "4200000065",
      "@type": "String",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Card_Status",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "Deactivated",
      "@type": "String",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Card_Type",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "SCRATCH1",
      "@type": "string",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "FaceValue",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "1000000",
      "@type": "string",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "cardExpiryDate",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "11",
      "@type": "string",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Recharge_Amount",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "1000000",
      "@type": "string",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "MSISDN",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "237654567",
      "@type": "string",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "manufacturer_order_no",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "47",
      "@type": "string",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "time_of_usage",
      "characteristicRelationship": [],
      "value": "2027-12-31T00:00:00.000Z",
      "@type": "string",
      "arrayIndex": "-1"
    }
  ],
  "serviceOrderItem": [],
  "serviceRelationship": [],
  "supportingResource": [],
  "supportingService": [],
  "responseHeader": {
    "requestId": "CRM3inpmh_1723552012193",
    "responeId": "CRM3inpmh_1723552012193",
    "responseMessage": "Success",
    "responseStatus": "200",
    "responseTimestamp": "2024-08-13T17:56:52.425Z",
    "source": "cellcardESB"
  }
}

Current jolt spec:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "responseMessage": "resultDesc",
        "responseStatus": "resultcode"
      },
      "characteristic": {
        "*": {
          "value": {
            "@(1,value)": "@(2,arrayIndex).@(2,name)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "-1": "bundlelist[]",
      "*": "RechargeResource[]",
      "resultcode": "resultcode",
      "resultDesc": "resultDesc"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "resultcode": "resultcode",
      "resultDesc": "resultDesc",
      "bundlelist": {
        "*": {
          "SerialNo": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardSerialNumber",
          "Card_Status": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardStatus",
          "cardValue": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardValue",
          "Card_Type": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardType",
          "FaceValue": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].faceValue",
          "cardExpiryDate": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardStopDate",
          "Recharge_Amount": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].rechargeAmount",
          "MSISDN": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].msisdn",
          "manufacturer_order_no": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].manufacturerOrderNo",
          "time_of_usage": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].timeUsage"
        }
      },
      "RechargeResource": {
        "*": {
          "SerialNo": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardSerialNumber",
          "Card_Status": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardStatus",
          "cardValue": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardValue",
          "Card_Type": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardType",
          "FaceValue": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].faceValue",
          "cardExpiryDate": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].cardStopDate",
          "Recharge_Amount": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].rechargeAmount",
          "MSISDN": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].msisdn",
          "manufacturer_order_no": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].manufacturerOrderNo",
          "time_of_usage": "datas.cardDetails.[&1].timeUsage"
        }
      }
    }
    }
]

current output:
{
  "resultcode": "200",
  "resultDesc": "Success",
  "datas": {
    "cardDetails": [
      {
        "cardSerialNumber": "4200000065",
        "cardStatus": "Deactivated",
        "cardType": "SCRATCH1",
        "faceValue": "1000000",
        "cardStopDate": "",
        "rechargeAmount": "1000000",
        "msisdn": "237654567",
        "manufacturerOrderNo": "47",
        "timeUsage": "2027-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Note: If any of the field value is empty or null that needs to be removed.
expected output like below:
{
  "resultcode": "200",
  "resultDesc": "Success",
  "datas": {
    "cardDetails": [
      {
        "cardSerialNumber": "4200000065",
        "cardStatus": "Deactivated",
        "cardType": "SCRATCH1",
        "faceValue": "1000000",
        "rechargeAmount": "1000000",
        "msisdn": "237654567",
        "manufacturerOrderNo": "47",
        "timeUsage": "2027-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}


Indeed what you need is this much ( principally matching value vs. name ) except for renaming of the attributes  :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "responseStatus|responseMessage": "&"
      },
      "characteristic": {
        "*": {
          "@value": "datas.cardDetails[0].@name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

converting to the one with renaming, you can make :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "responseHeader": {
        "responseStatus|responseMessage": "&"
      },
      "characteristic": {
        "*": {
          "@value": "datas.cardDetails[0].@name"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "responseStatus": "resultcode",
      "responseMessage": "resultDesc",
      "datas": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "SerialNo": "&3.&2[&1].cardSerialNumber",
            "Card_Status": "&3.&2[&1].cardStatus",
            "Card_Type": "&3.&2[&1].cardType",
            "FaceValue": "&3.&2[&1].faceValue",
            "cardExpiryDate": "&3.&2[&1].&",
            "Recharge_Amount": "&3.&2[&1].rechargeAmount",
            "MSISDN": "&3.&2[&1].msisdn",
            "manufacturer_order_no": "&3.&2[&1].manufacturerOrderNo",
            "time_of_usage": "&3.&2[&1].timeUsage"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

